# See the code coverage of my package without uploading it

Tags: apex, package, unit-test, code-coverage

I have a packaging org of a managed package and only 60% of its classes are actually part of my managed package. How or where can I check the code coverage of only those packaged classes without actually uploading it?

I'm asking this as code coverage still is a bit of a guessing game when uploading a package. I have classes with to low coverage but when I check the coveraga page only comments or empty lines are not covered. In many cases I only find out about too low coverage when I actually have no time to fix it - right before uploading it.

Comment: As far as I know there's not really a quick way to do this. I sometimes calculate it manually by adding up the lines by hand. Also, note that if you change the class that's already tested, sometimes the code coverage highlighting is messed up, so I often clear the code coverage after I've done lot's of changes.

Comment: When possible, avoid having untested code in your development org. I know this is sometimes unavoidable, but being that getting an accurate count is nigh-impossible, You can make your development cycle easier if you refrain from having code that's not in your package in the org at all. For example, our flagship product exists in its own org, and has very few lines of extraneous code in the org (less than 100 lines, I believe). Our coverage is plus or minus about 1%, and we keep the coverage over 80% in any case.